# I want company-mode to show completions list after the second character

Tags: completion, company-mode

When typing in a buffer with company-mode the completions popup shows after typing the third character:

[image: emacs company popup]

Is it possible to do this after typing the first or second charater?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can set `company-minimum-prefix-length` to a desire value of your choice:

```
(setq company-minimum-prefix-length 2)
```

You can use the customize interface `M-x customize` and search for `company` in there using the search box. It will list relevant options related to the package. You can also search for a variable with <kbd>C-h v</kbd> or search for a command with <kbd>C-h a</kbd>, which is `apropos-command` is bound to by default. If you like interactive apropos that gives you everything: functions, commands and variables, and gives you instant feedback for every character entered), you can use [helm-apropos](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html#sec-14). Helm in general is really convenient and user friendly. See [my Helm guide](http://tuhdo.github.io/helm-intro.html) for details.

Comment: I was unable to find this on my own. Is there any good documentation on company-mode or do I have to look through company.el (I'm new to Emacs)?

Comment: @max0r answer updated.

Comment: @max0r Small (but important) correction: `C-h a` is bound to `apropos-command` by default, which won't look for matching variables. There is no default key binding for the `apropos` command, so you'll either have to set one up yourself or call the command via `M-x` `apropos` `RET`.

Comment: @max0r There is a recommendation to use `M-x customize-group` on the company-mode homepage.